# Re-open A Question

Tags: discussion, closing

[This one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/creepy-horror-fps-recommendations-closed). It's a recommendations thread.  It's harmless, and no different than people asking for PC TBS games.  I can't believe people voted to close it (I can, but that is a topic for another time).  These types of discussions are going to be common on a gaming site.

Comment: As Grace said in [this answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/529/re-open-a-question/531#531) there's a possibility that question will be re-opened when we have the scope clearly defined. We are in beta after all!

Comment: Should the question not be reopened, please consider supporting [this polling request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling).

Answer (score 18):

To be honest, we're in the middle of a scrambled situation here. When the site first came out, we had thought it was perfectly harmless to allow these kinds of questions - in moderation. But as time passed, during the end stages of the private beta and moreso as the public beta began, we noticed that the volume of these questions was overwhelmingly large. 38 questions tagged [game-rec] doesn't sound like a lot, compared to 714, but when many of them are occupying the front page, it doesn't look very good. It's also mixed in with several other kinds of questions that are just lists and repositories of games, rather than an actual knowledge share. When someone comes to visit this site and is looking for expert answers to problems, seeing a bunch of repositories is not going to illustrate that we are the place to go to. We end up looking like a place to just fraternize.

We don't have a defined scope on what kinds of recommendation questions are allowed - see [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/game-recommendations-and-single-correct-answers) and [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/are-suggestions-really-subjective-enough-to-close). We have not actually reached a consensus on this, so there's going to be a lot of back-and-forth, probably, for these. I myself realize that as much as it is *fun* to have these questions on the site, it detracts from the goal of the site to serve answers that experts are giving. And expertise is questionable, at best, when it comes to just listing games in a genre.

Keep in mind that, even in our FAQ draft, we explicitly state that we are not a discussion forum - we are not meant to be a place to hold extended discussions about the latest and hottest new games. We want to be addressing actual problems that people need solutions to in these. First and foremost, **before we are a gaming community, we are a gaming Q&A**.

So some of the users are now starting to crack down on them as they come up. And the users will eventually backtrack to review all of the older ones as well. We realize that not everyone agrees with this. Please check out some of the other discussions we're having - [on lists in general](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/475/best-favourite-subjective-list-type-questions) for example, review what some of the users have had to say in order to understand why we're cracking down on these. If you still disagree after reading our reasons, **please let us know what you think**. Feedback from users such as yourself is completely welcome - remember that if we want this site to survive the beta, we as a community need to shape it together. And you are part of that community.

Comment: Cannot +1 this enough.

Comment: Well, how about _not_ closing the threads until the consensus is reached. Moreover, the consensus has not been reached. Which means there is no consensus yet.

Comment: @HRJ, I think it would be very wrong to let them open now -- that would be like an open invitation for more questions of the same type, which would **very extremely ultra difficult** to find later and close them all should we decide they are not allowed (not to mention change the status-quo once everybody thinks they are indeed allowed).

Comment: very well said, and a classic example of where "give 'em what they asked for!" is a dangerous solution.

Answer (score 2):

There have been a lot of questions like this on the site, yes. So far, we've all closed them.

The point is that these kind of un-detailed questions are going to differ for everyone on the site. What's 'creepy' for you might not be creepy for me. StackExchange is based on an ask-once read-many concept, which means that though only one person asks the question, everyone who has this question should be able to benefit from it.

That's not possible for most kind of list questions because they differ from person to person.

Comment: You are missing a bunch, clearly:

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=Recommendation

And the whole point is that the answers differ from person to person.  But if it isn't your thing, it isn't your thing.

Comment: And if it isn't everyone's thing it shouldn't be on the site.
For example, this one is fine: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/579/looking-for-game-recommendations-similar-to-a-game-maxis-released-a-train-back because it's specific enough for anyone looking for a game similar to that game.

Comment: @peacedog, please read Grace Note's answer, I think it sums up the situation pretty well