# How should on-topic lists be answered?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, community-wiki

I just asked a list question with a finite number of objectively correct answers: [Which Fallout 3 items are sought-after by NPCs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/which-fallout-3-items-are-sought-after-by-npcs)

What should the answer format be?  I can think of two good options: each item in a separate answer and one large CW answer.  Which do we prefer?

Answer (score 4):

As I mention in my answer [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/776/voting-on-the-future-of-list-of-x-questions/808#808), a single answer to contain a list is going to be preferable in any scenario where the list is what is sought after. You can add a great wealth of detail to one large answer without needing to break it up into separate answers. We're really not designed to handle one-per-answer smoothly.

As far as if CW is necessary - [only when you are planning or intending for collaboration](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/849/what-is-the-use-case-for-community-wiki/854#854). The fact that it is a list of items/elements/NPCs in a game is irrelevant.

Also when considering an objective list, [consider the scope and not how large it is, but how useful it is](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-large-can-an-objective-questions-scope-get/866#866).

---

I'll head off any attempts to warp this into a defense of list of X. There's two differences here from what is being discussed in this question and what is being argued for and against on Meta.

1. Recommendations are subjective and based on opinion. Game content is based on experience and knowledge, and is authoritative information.
2. Non-rec lists of games and lists of game content are both authoritative information. We have more users who can cater to the latter due to the more selective knowledge. Compiling good game lists is a lot harder than content lists, and we aren't [encouraging towards repository experts](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/what-level-of-exclusion-is-healthy-for-the-site-at-this-point/819#819).

Comment: Thanks; this is pretty much exactly what I was hoping someone would say.

Comment: Not only do I agree, I think alexander did a good job answering it here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6149/which-fallout-3-items-are-sought-after-by-npcs/6152#6152

Comment: @tzenes, not so; his answer, despite getting a torrent of upvotes, is not CW... and it's incomplete!

Comment: @pop If it's incomplete feel free to provide comments or a better answer, but I don't see how it requires community collaboration?