# One Question, One Answer. Or Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

So I'm a little confused.

Do we try to go for one question, one answer, or maybe a community wiki style? The latter seems more like a database of information rather than a question being answered.

For example,

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106407/what-are-the-new-terran-units-in-heart-of-the-swarm-and-how-should-i-use-them

[What are the new units in Heart of the Swarm?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106408/what-are-the-new-zerg-units-in-heart-of-the-swarm-and-how-should-i-use-them)

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106409/what-are-the-new-protoss-units-in-heart-of-the-swarm-and-how-should-i-use-them

Are all different questions that are asking similar but distinctly different questions.

Raven then pointed me to: [What are some pros and cons of the different races?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4016/what-are-some-pros-and-cons-of-the-different-races)

Maybe I just don't understand what a community wiki is or how we should be using it.

I've found [What is the Use Case for Community Wiki](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/849/what-is-the-use-case-for-community-wiki) and read it as well. But I still don't understand why we would take 3 separate questions, each very distinct per race, and turn it into a case where we have it as a community wiki answer.

Comment: I don't see any reason why those questions or answers should be community wiki. Also, you should note that two of those questions have been deleted and the remaining one has been changed.

Comment: I know they are deleted, but those with 10k rep as well as mods can see them. Even the edited one you can click to see the original form. I'm getting the feeling that the answer for the question that is still existing, could be turned into that if I were to go by what Raven had said about a question having multiple answers.

Answer (score 2):

> Do we try to go for one question, one answer, or maybe a community wiki style?

Going for one answer is preferable, *unless* you want the community to vote separately on each of your answers.

For example, in the remaining question asking for a list of changes, there's no need to have us cast votes on each change. We're here to vote *the answer*, not *the single change;* making one answer per change would turn the question into a popularity contest ("omfg yes!!! zerg nerf +1").

On the other hand, consider an hypothetical question asking how to get an item in Minecraft. You can answer this in a few fundamentally different ways:

- Acquire it with the game.
- Cheat your way to creative mode.
- Use `/give`.

Lumping these completely different approaches in the same answer may or may not make sense based on how you're wording your answer. In this case, you may want to split your knowledge in multiple answers and let the community vote on the fitness of each approach.